# In ODL files - is it necessary or useful to list extra interfaces in the coclass?

Tags: c#, c++, com

Without adding any **extra** interfaces to the coclass section of a dispinterface in ODL, I'm still able to QueryInterface for IFoo, IBar etc. I can also cast in C# to those different interfaces, and use the 'as' keyword successfully. Their presence or absence in the coclass part of the ODL, makes no visible difference as far as I can tell.

I can see the logic of declaring the default and event interfaces, but what discernable benefit do consumers get if I add IFoo and IBar to the coclass section in the ODL? As I've not seen anywhere in C# that takes advantage of the fact these are advertised. Is it purely private commentary for the designer?

Comment: It plays no role at runtime, it is annotation that can be read back from the type library.  Not different from the way .NET metadata works, you can try to cast an object reference to any interface and the compiler assumes you know what you're doing.  null if you guessed wrong.  it does matter somewhat to a .NET program that uses a COM server, the type library importer uses this annotation to generate a fake .NET class (name ends with "Class") that is a merge of all the interfaces implemented by the coclass.

Comment: @HansPassant if you write that as an answer, I'd accept it! Well done, I hadn't noticed the additions to the FooClass, I'd been just looking at the IFoo import. We generally avoid using the xxxClass definitions - is there a performance benefit?